# Ссылки в друпале

Tags: drupal, html, cms

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема. Распаковал сайт из архива разместил на локальном хостинге, установил соответсвующую бд.Главная страница отображается нормально,а если перейти на другую страницу,переходит только если к названию страницы дописать "?q=", а без этого дополнения выдается ошибку.

Comment: Файл .htaccess проверяй, там всё на Mod_rewrite закручено, если не ошибся с названием модуля.

Comment: у меня кажется этого файла даже нету, по крайней мере в главной папке с сайтом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно проверить включен ли `mod_rewrite`.
За пути в адресной строке без `?q=` отвечает модуль `path`. 
Его нужно включить.

Comment: Модуль включен. Проблема вся в том, что сайт переходя по страницам он переходит на страницы без "?q=", чтобы страницы открылись надо добавлять к названию страницы "?q="

Comment: Нужно проверить включен ли mod_rewrite.

Comment: как это сделать?

Comment: в .htaccess пишем   

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule p1.html p2.html

Создаем пару простых страницы, и набираем адрес http://<ваше доменное имя>/p1.html.   
Должна пройти переадресация на страницу p2.html

Comment: создал файл в главной папке с сайтом .htaccess написал эти 2 строчки, эффекта ноль

Comment: Значит не включен mod_rewrite

Comment: Файле httpd.conf перед строками:

    #AddModule mod_rewrite.c  
    #LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so  

Уберите символ # и перезапустите apache

Answer (score 0):

В файле .htaccess нужно найти   `# RewriteBase /drupal` и   `# RewriteBase /` и удалить перед ними знак #, сохранить файл и включить "Чистые ссылки" в админке друпала. (http://site.com/admin/config/search/clean-urls)